# PHP 5 - xml parsing

Tags: php, xml

How to parse below xml (i.e in this xml some tag contains the prefix "soap" ) in php 5? Please any one show me an example?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Header>
    <AuthorizationToken xmlns="http://www.avectra.com/OnDemand/2005/">
      <Token>string</Token>
    </AuthorizationToken>
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
    <AuthenticateResponse xmlns="http://www.avectra.com/OnDemand/2005/">
      <AuthenticateResult>string</AuthenticateResult>
    </AuthenticateResponse>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: Have you considered using the `SoapClient` (and related) classes?? Alternatively you can look into `SimpleXML`.

Comment: @user670616 You've asked 14 questions so far and you haven't accepted a single answer. I hope that's not a complaint about the quality of our answers ;-P

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php

Answer (score 0):

PHP has a specific library for SOAP:

- http://es.php.net/manual/en/book.soap.php

Unluckily, the official documentation doesn't seem to have examples. Here's the first one I found in Google that doesn't seem outdated:

- http://www.vankouteren.eu/blog/2009/03/simple-php-soap-example/

Answer (score 0):

> See in this link Here is a xml file that is parsed using simple php script no need of external modules

[PHP XML Parser](https://github.com/anujsinghwd/XML_Parser_PHP/blob/master/index.php)